# "Where" and "Join" in PomQL?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have two Prometheus metrics that report samples every day:

- metric A: **product_bugs**, it's a gauge, it has a label for type of product (X, Y, Z). It reports the number of bugs for a product type.
- metric B: **supported**, it's a gauge (either 0 or 1). It has also a product type. It reports 0 if it's out of support, otherwise 1.

I want to display the total bugs but only for products that are still under support.

I'm guessing this requires the use of promql function sum and the equivalent of join or where clauses? What would be the ideal PromQL for it? using Grafana.

Comment: did you try one of: `product_bugs and supported` or `product_bugs and on (product_type) supported`?

Comment: @star67, my understanding is that `supported` is always present (being 0 in value), and thus simple `and` wouldn't work. But `sum(product_bugs and supported == 1)` should. Consider posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that `supported` takes values 0 and 1, and you want to left only those with value 1, you can simply multiply your metrics and then sum them up:

```
sum(product_bugs * supported)
```

This query is based on the assumption that metrics `product_bugs` and `supported` have exactly the same label sets.

If this is not the case, you'll need to use [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches):

```
sum(product_bugs * on(product) supported)
```

where `product` is the name of the label you mentioned in the question (with values X, Y, Z)